# Retrieving type after reading from json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Lets say I write the following to a JSON file

```
data = {
    number : 10,
    string : "Hey stackoverflow!"
}
```

After I JSON.stringify (data) it writes it to a file as

```
 {
    "number" : "10",
    "string" : "Hey stackoverflow!"
 }
```

So when I read the file, number is now a string. Is there anywhere to preserve the type when reading/writing to JSON files?

I am using node js to write to the file (fs.writeFile) and reading the JSON file using Javascript on the client side.

Comment: `JSON.parse( data );` should work for you

Comment: If you're calling `JSON.stringify()` on the `data` object you've presented, `number` should *not* get converted to a string.

Comment: Really? Stringify works fine for me: `JSON.stringify({"number": 10})` ->

`'{"number":10}'`

Comment: You are drawing the wrong conclusion. Your input data must already be a string. You should fix that.

Comment: Whoops, it was when I sent it over to my server

Answer (score 3):

`JSON.stringify( data )` won't convert numbers to strings. Double-check that the type of `10` is actually a number and not a string. `JSON.parse( strData )` will then bring it back as a number correctly.

**Example**

`JSON.stringify({number: 10})` gives `'{"number":10}'`. (Note, no double quotes around the 10 as in your example.

`JSON.parse('{"number":10}')` brings the number back as expected.

Comment: I wasn't sending it over to my server in the correct format. Thanks